# What is the use of node--product_display.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, commerce

I am new to [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), what is the use of `node--product_display.tpl.php`?

Answer (score 0):

`node.tpl.php` is the default theme for all content types in a drupal installation.  If you want a specific content type to have different layout/theme you can override by creating a tpl.php file like this `node--[CONTENTTYPENAME].tpl.php` so for example for ARTICLE content type your would copy `node.tpl.php` and rename to `node--article.tpl.php` and adjust the new file to as you desire.

Now Commerce displays a product using a CONTENT type called product display thus to change the look of this content type you will create `node--product_dispaly.tpl.php`

here is some more explanation of things that you can do inside a node.tpl.php file and (all overrides) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7.x

Answer (score 0):

File ending with `.tpl.php` extension are template files used for defining the HTML output of anything like Page, Node, Region, Block, Comment, etc.

When working (overriding) with node.tpl.php (used to override HTML of content) 2nd part after `--` consist of Content Type name or Content ID. i.e. node--[content_type|nodeid].tpl.php. File `node--product_display.tpl.php` is used to override/re-write HTML of Content of Content (Node) Type **Product Display**.

Read more details about [Template (theme hook) suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions).